# Editor invited after minor revision submitted

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors, journal-workflow

According to editor guideline on springer website "Accept with minor revisions is actually a commitment to ultimately publish the paper, provided the authors answer the remaining concerns (which should be relatively minor) in a timely and proper way." 
However, one of my article which was accepted with minor revision is now  under "Editor Invited" status after the submission of revised version. I sent an email to editor, who was handling my article, he said he can not see revised version on system.
Is it possible that an article might be handed over to another editor at final stages by journal office without notifying the handling editor?
How it can affect the overall review process? Should I expect more delay and more chances of rejection even the decision was Accept with minor revisions?

Comment: I would write a letter to the editor in chief, because he is the person in charge of the editorial process.

Comment: I have the same situation now. Would you please share your experience? Thank you.

Comment: I think this is meaningless.

Comment: There is no way for anyone without access to the journal's editorial system to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar story recently. It was with the handling editor who will go through the comments and replies and also reviewers new comments. The final outcome was "accept".

So if authors have responded all the reviewers' comments appropriately, then most probably it will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely explanation for what happened is that the journal office is the one who assigns editors, and by default they assign the editor-in-chief / managing editor who then assigns the handling editor.

So paper's status is your revised paper was submitted -> journal office invites editor-in-chief -> waiting for editor-in-chief to invite handling editor.

Unless the handling editor is inactive (which she isn't, since she answered your query), it would be pretty unusual for the editor who handled the original paper to not handle the revised one.